# Sending the same item to multiple recipients

Tags: product, checkout, cart, multiselect-attribute

We want to allow our customers to send a gift in quantities higher than 1, (for example, 20 of the same set of candles,) to multiple recipients, (in our case, 20 unique recipients for the candles.)

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Nothing yet. We are about to build it. The core experience for the user is write a thank you note that is turned into a hand written note on beautiful stationary that is sent to the recipient. The user can also attach a gift. We want to offer corporate gifting so a user can select 20 scented candles, and the send them out to 20 different recipients. From my understanding, we need this to be treated as one order on the front end, but 20 orders on the back end. We are using OpenERP for fulfillment.

Comment: and thank you for being so swift to respond.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the "checkout with multi addresses" option. That will allow you to add as many addresses as you like, and set the quantity of the products you want to send to each address.

If it's something that a lot of your customers will be doing, then I'd recommend creating a cms page to explain how to use the feature.

Comment: Thank you James. I hope it is this simple. For some reason, our developers told me last night that they would need to put a couple of engineers on this and that we would have to write significant extensions to Margento in order to pull this off.

Comment: Agree about the cms page. We definitely need to include this